# How to give user role by user id? I want to type user id in command (arguments)

Tags: discord, discord.js

How to give user role by user id?

I want to type user id in command.
E.g:

$add userid

I try a lot but I don't know how to do this

**My script (not working):**

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
const prefix = "$";

client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {return}
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if(command === 'add') {
    let member = guild.client.id();  
    if (member) {
      var role= member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "newrole");
      member.addRole(role);
    }
  }
})


client.login('token');
```

Comment: This is what you are looking for : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch `client.users.fetch(id).addRole(yourRole)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your code didn't really make much sense so I fixed it and got a version that should work for what you want.

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
const prefix = "$";

client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args[0].toLowerCase();
  if(command === 'add') {
    let member = message.member.guild.member(args[1])
    if (member) {
      var role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "newrole");
      message.guild.member(args[1]).roles.add(role)
    }
  }
})


client.login('token');
```

Comment: This will assign the role to the author of the message, not the user whose ID is in the message content

Comment: Also are you sure an ID in a string is a [`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) for `guild.member` ?

Comment: const command = args[0]toLowerCase();
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 :d

Comment: @onotyl added the dot. sorry about that

Comment: @Levi_OP now: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'member' before initialization

Comment: @onotyl Replace `let member = member.guild.member(args[1])` by `let member = client.users.fetch(args[1])`

Comment: @Seblor would that not be a problem if the user was not in the server? then it would attempt to give the role to someone who exists but is not in the server...

Comment: @onotyl on what line?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (path:12:31)
12 line

Comment: var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "newrole"); this line

Comment: oh it should say message.member.guild not member.guild let me edit

Comment: client.users.fetch(...).addRole is not a function

Comment: ok i change client.users.fetch to message.member.guild.member

Comment: message.member.guild.member(...).addRole is not a function

Comment: message.guild.member(...).addRole is not a function

Comment: ahhh the code i was using was for v11 let me update it to discordjs 12 ok try now

Answer (score 0):

Defining user might be useful for you so
`let user = message.mentions.users.first();`
And instead `member.addRole(role);`
Try using `user.id.addRole(role);`
Not sure if it will work for you

Comment: Apparently OP is using the id of the user, not the mention